# USB Disconnects Itself and Freezes Finder

Tags: disk-utility, usb

I have a Kingston DataTraveller USB: whenever I plug it into my Mac, it appears as a drive, but any attempts to see the folders on it, or format it, or otherwise do anything to it, the program in question simply freezes (e.g., Disk Utility freezes upon trying show the drive, Finder freezes upon trying to open it)

Any tips on how to debug the issue?

Comment: Was it used on this Mac before? Tried it on a different OS?

Comment: macOS version?  Once mounted, try using Terminal to view the contents.  `ls /Volumes/<name of mount>`. See if it generates any errors.

Comment: Using `ls` unfortunately just shows "Directory does not exist"... However, I've now got it to work with my iPad of all devices, which it previously didn't work with. Weird!